# Javascript Object Prototype falling out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I am currently writing a small Javascript Object which will add click listeners onto certain elements which then trigger an AJAX call to a PHP function. This is all working fine however, I want to call a function when the AJAX responds. I have made this happen by passing a function to the AJAX call which will be triggered when the response is given.

The problem I am having is that I am losing the scope of the object when passing through the protoytype as a call back (in order to stop the aynschronous problems that can occur with AJAX calls). The 'this' object (or self) is set to the window and not the instance of the object I have created. Here is my code:

```
    //Rating Submit
var Rater = function(element, videoId, ratingStars, userId) {
    this.userId = userId,
    this.element = element;
    this.videoId = videoId;
    this.ratingStars = ratingStars;
    var self = this;

    jQuery(this.ratingStars).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.ratingClick(this, self.changeStar);
    });
}

Rater.prototype.ratingClick = function(item, changeStar) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type     : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        url      : 'api/rate-video',
        data     : "userId=" + this.userId + "&videoId=" + this.videoId + "&rating=" + jQuery(item).attr("data-score"),
        success  : function(data) {
            changeStar(data, item);     
        }
    });
}

Rater.prototype.changeStar = function(response, item) {
    var maxCount = jQuery(item).attr("data-score"); 
    //console.log(self);
    jQuery(self.ratingStars).each(function(key, value) {
        alert(key);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am passing the 'self.changestar' prototype function to the AJAX call for this to be called when a response is given. When I try and access any of the variable I set in the constructor for that particular instance though, it says it is the Window object and not an instance of the class. Is it possible to pass through a prototype function as a call back from within the instance? I hope I have explained myself ok....

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you do this:

```
self.ratingClick(this, self.changeStar);
```

you have exactly the same problem you had in `Rating` with the jQuery click callback, which you solved with your `self` variable: Only the function reference, `changeStar`, gets passed, nothing about what value to use as `this` when calling it.

One solution is to use `Function#bind`, which you call on a function to get back another function that, when called, will call the original with a specific `this` value (and optional arguments):

```
self.ratingClick(this, self.changeStar.bind(self));
```

Alternately, you could pass the value to use as `this` separately:

```
self.ratingClick(this, self.changeStar, self);
```

...and then use `Function#call` in the success handler:

```
Rater.prototype.ratingClick = function(item, changeStar, thisArg) { // <== Change here
    jQuery.ajax({
        type     : 'post',
        dataType : 'json',
        url      : 'api/rate-video',
        data     : "userId=" + this.userId + "&videoId=" + this.videoId + "&rating=" + jQuery(item).attr("data-score"),
        success  : function(data) {
            changeStar.call(thisArg, data, item);                   // <=== And here
        }
    });
}
```